# how to assign a list or string to current-prefix-arg?

Tags: isearch, prefix-argument

`current-prefix-arg`'s 
help doc says, the variable can contain a list (or) number (or) minus symbol. I mostly set a number as the `prefix-arg` by keypress, `C-[1-9]`. 

But how can i assign a list or string to `current-prefix-arg`?
   I ask this, since `isearch-forward`

```
(defun isearch-forward (&optional regexp-p no-recursive-edit)
  (interactive "P/np")
  (........))
```

takes the search string through interactive key "P"  but i am having zero clue on how to set a string to this prefix-arg?

Comment: `isearch-forward` does *not* take a string.  It's just a command that starts the search or makes isearch jump to the next occurrence.

Comment: `current-prefix-arg` corresponds to 'C-u', not the search string itself.

Comment: @wasamasa, you say regexp-p is not the search string? i see `isearch-forward` internally calls `isearch-mode` to do its work. how does the minibuffer prompt's input get passed onto the `isearch-mode` function?

Comment: The name `regexp-p` indicates that it's a boolean value, in this case it's probably about whether the search is involving regex or not. Same applies to the other argument. I don't know how it obtains the search string, but be assured, it's lots of advanced magic judging by the docstrings.

Comment: The minibuffer is not used for Isearch (except when you use `M-e` to edit the search string. Instead, each key you hit invokes a command (as usual), and for most self-inserting keys the command appends the key's character to the search string (and then searches for the updated string).

Comment: @Drew, ""each key you hit invokes a command"", which command/function is that? i tried `find-function-on-key`, but the moment i press `M-x`, it comes out of the `isearch-mode`

Comment: In Emacs, in general, each key you hit invokes a command. In Isearch, (speaking generally) the keys that normally invoke the command `self-insert-command` instead cause the Isearch code to append the character to the search string and then update the search based on the updated string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a list with `C-u`, but not possible to assign a string.

`current-prefix-arg`'s help doc says (at least in Emacs 24):

> It may be a number, or the symbol `-' for just a minus sign as arg,
>   or **a list whose car is a number for just one or more C-u's**
>   or nil if no argument has been specified.

That is, a) it is not a general list nor [`Sequence`, of which `String` is a member](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequences-Arrays-Vectors.html#Sequences-Arrays-Vectors), b) the list is generated by a `C-u` or more of.

You can see the list generated by `C-u` with the following command, which is taken from [Prefix Command Arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html) in the [GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/).

```
(defun display-prefix (arg)
  "Display the value of the raw prefix arg."
  (interactive "P")
  (message "%s" arg))
```

`C-u M-x display-prefix` shows **a list** whose value is `(4)` in the minibuffer.